# Get the nested value of aggregation result at top level

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I made an aggregation query in MongoDB.

```
{
    "productData" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("634020b72f772f0f828eadaa"),
        "name": "shoe",
        "price": 450
    }
}
```

but how can I get just the nested part in my query result like

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634020b72f772f0f828eadaa"),
    "name": "shoe",
    "price": 450
}
```

Which aggregation stage should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`$replaceWith`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceWith/) stage to replace the input document with `productData` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: "$productData"
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Oie7WJF_hFD)